# Batch - Can't print spaces beginning of a string

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, command

I have a command called compare which returns a number. I want to print some spaces and then "text" then the number to a file. Expected output is like:

```
    text1
```

My code prints `text1` with no spaces

```
set "output=     text"
<nul set /p "=!output!" >> "%resultFile%"
compare -metric NCC "a.jpg" "b.jpg" "c.jpg" 2>> "%resultFile%"
```

I tried to print a tab character `echo <TAB> >> "%resultFile%"` but it gave me an error ">> was unexpected at this time." What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works well:

```
set "output=     text"
>> "%resultFile%" echo %output%
```

So what about appending the command output in the batch itself?

```
set "output=     text"
call compare -metric NCC "a.jpg" "b.jpg" "c.jpg" 2> temp.txt
set /p number=<temp.txt
del temp.txt
>> "%resultFile%" echo %output%%number%
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2340018/711006. I’d prefer the `for` option but it does not work for the error output.

**EDIT**

The OP suggested editing the last line to this:

```
echo !output!!number! >> "%resultFile%"
```

The `!`’s instead of `%`’s are needed when the commands are expanded together, for example as a part of an `if` or `for` block. However, one has to issue the command `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` before and we have not mentioned this in this question.

And I would recommend further reading about swapping the command and output redirection: [Problems with an extra space when redirecting variables into a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898556/problems-with-an-extra-space-when-redirecting-variables-into-a-text-file/21898611#21898611)

Comment: @ozcanovunc Please paste suggestions on code changes into comments next time, so we can discuss the change together and everyone can follow our thoughts.